# 「の為の」 in certain contexts

Tags: grammar

So I've seen this usage of 為 pop up twice now and I still can't figure out what its exact meaning is supposed to be, here's the two cases in question:

1. I found this one in a videogame, where the information filtration system of a facility is explained:
   「多様性学習の為のエラー許容率は７．２１％」
   *The accepted diversity-learning error rate is 7.21%.*
   Disregarding whatever this sentence is supposed to mean, could I replace「の為の」with just「の」or even「による」and retain the same meaning? What would the difference be?
2. This one's from a scene in the Jojo manga where the protagonist is fighting somebody underwater - he's charging his attack to launch it at the enemy and as is customary for Japanese media, announces and shouts his attack while doing so, exclamating:
   「水中のための青緑波紋疾走（たーコイズブルーオーバードライブ）」
   *Underwater turquoise ripple dash* (or somesuch, where does the 'blue' part come from anyway?)
   Now I'm really unsure what the「のための」here is supposed to insinuate exactly. Could I just leave that part out and still end up with the same meaning?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: For reference, I'll add the full transcript I found the first sentence in question in:

> 『塔』システム概略
> "本『塔』は射出装置を中心に資源回収ユニットから送られた各資源を処理・情報化する為の施設である
> 256階層から成る構造体は情報濁度2300以
> 下の情報物質を濾過処理・圧縮から射出体への記
> 録まで27分32秒で行う(※)
> アンドロイド達を分解消化する為のルートについては詳細を別途記載する
> ※多様性学習の為のエラー許容率は7.21%"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～のための just means "for (the sake of) ～" or "(in order) to ～".

1. This phrase sounds puzzling to me because エラー許容率 does not seem to be something that will benefit 多様性学習. But if this エラー許容率 is something that has to be *high* enough to achieve 多様性学習, it would make sense (i.e., "the 'accepted error rate' value *for* achieving diversity-learning"). Without understanding the detailed study design, I cannot say if it's correct to use のための here or if it's safe to replace this のための to の.
2. 水中のための波紋疾走 just means "波紋疾走 *for* 水中", or a customized version of 波紋疾走 that can be used in water. Admittedly this のための sounds verbose and descriptive, but according to [this](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%B3%A2%E7%B4%8B%E7%96%BE%E8%B5%B0), 青緑波紋疾走 is the real name of this attack, and 水中のための波紋疾走 is supposed to be a verbose description. Usually, you can use 用 instead of のための after a kango word (e.g, 水中用カメラ "underwater camera", 実験用器具 "laboratory-use equipment", 家庭用ゲーム機 "home video game console").

---

**EDIT:** I read the whole context about the 塔. So this 塔 is something like an information processor, and its input (androids) must be "clean" enough (情報濁度2300以下). So the sentence should be "The *maximum* error rate to perform the diversity learning is 7.21%" (i.e., if the input androids have more error/noise than this, the tower cannot perform the diversity learning).

Comment: I added the full transcript for the first question, maybe it'll help in understanding better. Though your idea seems to make sense in this context, as in a certain error rate is necessary to facilitate some sort of learning process. Initially I thought it was supposed to say "the accepted error rate caused by diversity-learning is 7.21%" but I'm not sure how much sense this would make.

As for the second one, in the manga it actually says 水中のための青緑波紋疾走 but I guess it's all the same nevertheless. Just thought it a little odd to have のための here as it seemed a little... redundant?

Comment: @Boolicious Please see the edit. As for 波紋疾走, yes it might look a bit redundant, but here three elements coexist to refer to the same thing (kanji name `青緑`, the katakana reading `ターコイズ` and the verbose description `水中のための`), so it might have been hard to avoid confusion.